# RecyclerView cell's shadow getting clipped

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I intend to increase the elevation of the cell when user starts dragging and decrease the elevation when user drops it. Upon drag start, shadow due to elevation is getting clipped. Any ideas how to fix it?
I have tried to add `clipChildren = false` and `clipToPadding = false` on recyclerview but it made no difference. Using `cardView.setCardElevation` to set the elevation in code. Any ideas?

RecyclerView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/blrtMediaSelector_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/blrtMediaSelector_addBtn"
        app:layout_behavior="blrtapp.droid.mediaPicker.AddButtonBehaviour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mediaSelectorCell_cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mediaSelectorCell_parentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@color/white">
    <!-- thumbnail -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mediaSelectorCell_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/blrtMediaSelectorCell_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/blrtMediaSelectorCell_size"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/splash" />
    <!-- select icon -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mediaSelectorCell_selectIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/mediaSelectorCell_thumbnail"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/mediaSelectorCell_thumbnail"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
    <!-- container for text fields -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mediaSelectorCell_textContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mediaSelectorCell_thumbnail"
            android:paddingStart="6dp"
            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- primary text -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mediaSelectorCell_primaryTex"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/charcoal"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Primary text"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        <!-- secondary text -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mediaSelectorCell_secondaryText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/gray4"
                android:text="secondary text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    <!-- anchor to drag the cell -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mediaSelectorCell_dragAnchorButton"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/media_drag"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**PLEASE DISREGARD THIS IT IS JUST TO MEET THE REQUIREMENTS OF MINIMUM DETAILS AS CODE IS A LOT MORE THAN TEXT**

Answer (score 3):

If the button sits at the bottom of the parent, 
The parent `ViewGroup` may also be clipping the shadow.

Make sure the parent has padding and set `android:clipToPadding="false"` on the parent

Comment: Which button are you talking about? There is a cardview (which is at the root of the cell layout) that needs to cast a shadow due to elevation. No cell at the moment cast shadow correctly let alone the one at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Also add

```
cardView.setOutlineProvider(android.view.ViewOutlineProvider.BOUNDS);
cardView.setClipToOutline(false);
```

This worked for me to generate shadows in a RecyclerView.

Comment: This will require api21 if in xml (android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView)

Comment: Also, I tried the same for the same problem as that of OP. It doesn't work at all